# MockWebServer: llegalStateException: start() already called

Tags: android-testing, mockwebserver

I try to run a test with [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

I would like to make a UI test with mocked response, so I could test for valid\invalid UI changes like logging in, or showing error in a login API.

However, each and every time I ran the code I got the **following exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: start() already called
```

**Code:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class UITestPlayground {

    String testUrl = "http://testurl.com/";
    MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<LoginActivity> mIntentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void beforeHelper() throws IOException {
        TestHelper.removeUserAndTokenIfAny(mIntentsRule.getActivity());
        URLS.baseUrl = testUrl;
        server.url(URLS.baseUrl);
        //try to shutting down the server JUT IN CASE...
        server.shutdown();
        server.start();

    }

    @After
    public void afterHelper() throws IOException {
        server.shutdown();
    }


    @Test
    public void invalidLoginDueNotValidJSONResponse() {

        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("Something not valid JSON response"));

        String emailToBeTyped = "tester@tester.com";
        String passToBeTyped = "passtest";

        ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard();
        // Type text and then press the button.
        onView(withId(R.id.login_email_edit)).perform(typeText(emailToBeTyped));
        ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard();
        onView(withId(R.id.login_pass_edit)).perform(typeText(passToBeTyped));
        ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard();
        onView(withId(R.id.log_in_btn)).perform(click());

        //TODO: check on valid error message appearing

    }
 }
```

---

What am I doing wrong? **The .start() only called once, I even .shutdown()** just in 
case... I don't understand how could it called more than once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the original example at [github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) I have found that the **order is reversed.**

You a**ctually start the server, THEN sets it's url.**

And not <s>setting the url then starting the server.</s>

Interesting.

Comment: You don't set the url you retrieve it and that's why you need to start the server first, in such a way that the server has already started listening to a url:port and it can return it to you. It looks like if you retrieve the url before starting then the server starts itself automatically to be able to return the url.